# create table statement of Mysql 5.0 issues

Tags: mysql

I have some questions relating to following create query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `mytbl` (
  `userID` varchar(100) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL default '',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

1. What character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL default ''
   means exactly?
2. What is ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC means?
3. What is the different for using ENGINE=MyISAM and ENGINE=InnoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are answers for three questions:

1. COLLATE sets the character set to be used. In this case it's just the usual collation. NOT NULL means that this field cannot store a NULL value, i.e. it has to have something in it. DEFAULT sets the default value of the field to an empty string ('').
2. ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC means that the MyISAM storage engine will use dynamic field sizes wherever possible. E.g. if you've declared a field to be of string type with a length of 50. If the data for that field in a particular record only uses 25 characters, only that amount of space is used in the database. With static field sizes, that field of that record would still use the full amount of space allocated (50).
3. The main difference between the MyISAM & InnoDB storage engines, is that MyISAM manages non-transactional tables, whereas InnoDB provide transaction-safe tables. MyISAM is the default.

Here are some techie references:

Storage engine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html
MyISAM storage formats (ROW_FORMAT): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-table-formats.html

Hope this helps!